# Explicit Linking of Dynamic Load Library and Runtime misconception

Tags: c++, windows, dll, runtime

I was working with DLLs in windows. I created one of them, and also I can successfully link my client program to the DLL. But I have a misconception. When I was reading about DLLs, there was a quote which is emphasized when a DLL loaded into memory, all program instances can use it. so it causes we use memory efficiently and code duplication never happened.

So I write a program and it could successfully load a DLL and use it. when the program was running, I executed a sample of the previous program in a different path which the DLL doesn't exist there but when I run the second program, it shows an error, the DLL doesn't load.

My assumption was when the first program loads the DLL into memory, so one instance of it exists in the memory, so I should use it again but it doesn't happen. So I wanted to know how multiple programs can use an instance of a DLL? how should I implement an example to test this behavior? Must the program have a sample of the DLL in the path of itself?

Sorry for bad English speaking also, I have to mention, I am a newbie programmer, not a professional. Sorry if you find out this question so stupid. It is my code:

Program.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef void(__cdecl *PtrSetInformation)(std::string, std::string, int);
typedef void(__cdecl *PtrShowInformation)(void);

auto main() -> int {
    HINSTANCE HandlerInstance = LoadLibrary(TEXT("LibEngine.dll"));

    if (!HandlerInstance) {
        std::cout << "DLL doesn't load successfuly." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Dll is loaded successfuly." << std::endl;
    }

    PtrSetInformation OSetInformation = reinterpret_cast<PtrSetInformation>(GetProcAddress(HandlerInstance, "SetInformation"));
    PtrShowInformation OShowInformation = reinterpret_cast<PtrShowInformation>(GetProcAddress(HandlerInstance, "ShowInformation"));

    if (!OSetInformation || !OShowInformation) {
        std::cout << "Function pointers doesn't initiliazed successfuly." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        OSetInformation("Mikhail", "Razborov", 24);
        OShowInformation();
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

My DLL Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string __name;
std::string __family;
int __age;

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SetInformation(std::string arg_name, std::string arg_family, int arg_age) {
        __name = arg_name;
        __family = arg_family;
        __age = arg_age;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl ShowInformation() {
        std::cout << "Your name is " << __name << " " << __family << std::endl;
        std::cout << "You are a " << __age << " year old programmer." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the in-memory image of the DLL might be shared (it isn't always), Windows still needs to access the on-disk copy when loading the .exe.  This is because you might have two different DLLs with the same name in different directories and Windows treats each of these as a separate entity.

The advent of Address Space Layout Randomisation (ASLR) has moved the goalposts with regard to DLL code being shared between processes.  Raymond Chen has blogged about this extensively, for example [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160413-00/?p=93301).